# Finding the limit of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

This is the only question from my homework that I can't seem to complete, here is the question.

> The sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is defined by $a_{1}=2$, and $a_{n+1}$ is defined by $$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n}+\frac{2}{a_{n}}\right)$$ for $n \geq1$. Assuming that $\{a_{n}\}$ converges, find its limit.

I've taken the limit of both sides and ended up with $l^2=1$ and $l^2=4$, assuming $l$ to be the limit, and neither answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $l=\dfrac12\left(l+\dfrac2l\right)$, then $\dfrac12l=\dfrac1l$, so $l^2=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a_{n+1}=a_n$; this we can do due to the assumption of convergence. Then we are left with
$$x=\frac12(x+1/x)$$
and you should be able to derive that the limit is $\sqrt2$.